# Javascript- Locking a string to prevent other methods from changing it

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to implement localization for a React application. I have strings such as:

```
const string = 'We at {COMPANY NAME} believe...'
```

So I want everything except my company name to be localized, because the company name shouldn't change if I change languages!

How do I lock the string, that contains the company name?

Comment: *I'm trying to implement localization for a React application* - what did you try? It's impossible to suggest anything without that.

Answer (score 1):

You could break up the full string and bring in the company string from a variable like this

```
const string = `We at ${companyName} believe...`
```

Notice you'll have to use ` instead of ' or " to be able to use the `${}` inside of a string

Comment: Back ticks. `\``

Answer (score 0):

You should use [temple strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) to resolve this issue.

For example:

```
const string = `We at ${COMPANY NAME} believe...`;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are setting the company name in JavaScript or getting it from another source and setting it to a variable, you could try [`Object.freeze()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze).

```js
//Company information
company_info = {
    name: 'Company Name'
};

//Freeze the company info
Object.freeze(company_info);

//Try to change the company name
company_info.name = 'New Company Name';

//Should still be 'Company Name'
console.log(company_info.name);
```

`Object.freeze()` will make the object immutable, meaning that it will not change.